# Visual Studio 2008 + Team Foundation Server 2008 = files not uploading to server, how to fix?

Tags: tfs

We are having two problems with Visual Studio Team System 2008.

Very rarely, if we make changes to our source code, and we try to upload it to the server, it doesn't recognize the changed files, and doesn't upload them.

Even worse, we also have a database file (extension .bak) that does not seem to get uploaded to the server, no matter how much it changes.

In short, the source control part of TFS is not doing is job.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Shane.

Comment: Yes, we have SP1 installed everywhere.

Comment: Can you provide the exact steps you're using to add the files?  And also the steps to download/verify the new versions?

Comment: Normally, we follow this cycle: (1) Edit a file (2) Check it into the server on computer A (3) check it out of the server on computer B. This cycle works 90% of the time, however, sometimes it fails to work. The problem could be related to the fact that sometimes, computer A works in "offline" mode. The only way we can fix the problem is to go into each file, do a dummy edit to change it, after that it checks into the server ok.

Comment: In addition, I think there's a bug in Team Viewer: if there is files of type "*.bak", it won't upload any changes made in them to the server, no matter what happens. Anyone know of a Hotfix to address this, or a workaround?

Comment: Are you using the Go Online feature added in Team Explorer 2008, tfpt online, tfpt tweakui, or some other mechanism to manage offline/online state?  Also, see here for a broad list of usability issues that have led to "incomplete checkin" complaints in the past: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/811665ed-e851-4287-8c79-653e35e1ea2d

Comment: Cheers for the link to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/811665ed-e851-4287-8c79-653e35e1ea2d, I'll work through these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never resolved the insidious issues of incomplete checkins.

So, we switched to SVN, and dropped TFS. Never regretted this decision, although it was a shame to dump all the work we'd put into setting up TFS, for lack of a basic functionality with bugs in a simple "sync files on computer A with computer B".